# Find a formula for $x_1^2 + x_2^2$ of the quadratic formula in terms of $a,b$, and $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions of a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

Find a
formula for $x_1^2 + x_2^2$
in terms of $a, b $ and $c$.

Comment: Any thoughts?  If nothing else, you might try the quadratic formula (there are easier ways, but brute force is good for some things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know:
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}\ ;\ x_1x_2=\frac{c}{a}$$.

We calculate:
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=x_1^2+2x_1x_2+x_2^2-2x_1x_2=(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2=\frac{b^2}{a^2}-2\cdot\frac{c}{a}=\frac{b^2-2ac}{a^2}$$.

Answer (score 3):

By the quadratic formula,
$$x_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
and
$$x_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
then
$$x_1^2+x_2^2=\left(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)^2$$

Comment: $=\frac{b^2}{a^2}-\frac{2 c}{a}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  for yet another approach, $x_{1,2}$ satisfy the equation, so:

$$
\begin{cases}
ax_1^2 = -bx_1-c \\
ax_2^2 = -bx_2-c
\end{cases}
$$

Adding the two equalities gives $a(x_1^2+x_2^2) = -b(x_1+x_2)-2c\,$, then all that's left is to remember that $x_1+x_2=-b/a$ by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), or directly by the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).